# Entity Framework, C# and super-classes

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, inheritance, superclass

I have 6 100% equal tables in my Database, the only change is the names.
The look like this:

Offers_1, Offers_2, Offers_3 and so on..

If I use Entity Framework in my C# form I get 6 different classes, which of cause is named by the tables.
Is there a way that I can use a parent/super-class for these tables?
Maybe they could have an identifier saying which number they are or something like that.

I'm sure some one else must have had this problem before.

And to those wondering why I have 6 equal tables.
We have made our own way of switching in and out offers in our company, so we can operate on the offline tables and have maximum performance in the online tables.

Hopefully a helpful mind can guide me towards the light :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is your question?  If you have not at least attempted to solve the problem yourself that indicates you have not fully figured out the problem.  Its not clear what you mean by "super-classes" that term isn't a standard C# programming term.

Comment: I'm also wondering what the advantage would be of doing something like this.

Comment: The advantage is that I can work with the classes in my system.
Instead of creating a new Offer_1 AND Offer_2 AND etc...
I could create a single "Offer" and this would be system-wide

Comment: It seems strange to me that you need different tables at all.

Comment: Yes yes, I know - It's not my decision to take.
Our hosting department dictated this.

The thing is that only 3 tables is online at once, so we do not make any operations on the online tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to want to use Table Per Inheritance (TPH) : one table for multiple type.

This is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292.aspx) for model first.

This is explained (for example) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.4) for code first.

Comment: Hmm this seems interesting, but is it possible to do this without impacting the database (and therefore not creating a new table)?
I would be perfect if it could be a class which all the table-classes inherited from or something

Comment: No, for use TPH with EF you must have a discriminator column. I the DB exists yet you should use TPT (Table Per Type). For example have a base class. Derives your type for the base class, use code first to configure the derived type in the context with at least the `HasTable` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the row name from the .dbml file if you are using SQL to Linq tables.
By doing this you should be able to tell witch one you are using in your c# code.